# Localization in ASP.Net Core 2.0 Web Application

Tags: c#, localization, asp.net-core-2.0, globalization, razor-pages

I'm trying to globalize, and localize my ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web Application for Spanish. I'm trying to follow the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization), but it really seems like the docs were not meant for Core 2.0, as they don't seem to cover Razor Pages. Only Controllers & Views. Nevertheless, the localization isn't working whether I change the culture in the request headers, or use the query string as shown in the docs. Any insights into what I'm doing wrong?

```
 http://localhost:26417/?culture=es&ui-culture=es
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
{
    services.AddDbContext<PartDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PartDatabase"))
        );

    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Localization");
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
            //options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Index");
            // I can just use [AllowAnonymous] attribute
        })
        .AddViewLocalization()
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure( IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env )
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    var supportedCultures = new []
    {
        new CultureInfo("en"),
        new CultureInfo("es"),
    };
    app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions {
        DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("en"),
        SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
        SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
    });
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc(routes => {
        routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

**_ViewImports.cshtml**

```
@using PartDatabase
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@namespace PartDatabase.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
@inject  IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<a class="navbar-brand" asp-page="/Index">@Localizer["Part Database"]</a>
```

**File Structure**

[image]

**Resource File**

[image]

Notes:

- I tried moving _Layout.es.resx to the root of the Localization folder.
- I tried tried using "Resources" as the name instead of the name "Localization" as they show in the docs, but I would like to the believe the line `options.ResourcesPath = "Localization"` takes care of me using a different folder name.

Comment: Did it work with "Resources" as name of the folder?

Comment: @fatherOfWine, nope :-(, I think I'm going to try the [Orchard Core PO method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/portable-object-localization).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never got ViewLocalizer to work in layout pages, it seems to be for actual views only. To use localized strings in `_Layout.cshtml`, this is what I had to do.

#### 1. Create a dummy class

This is to be able to look up the resource file later. Path to resource file should reflect on where you put this file. For example, if you put the dummy file in `Models/_Shared.cs`, the resource file should be in `Resources/Models/_Shared.es.resx`.

```cs
namespace WebApp.Models
{
    // dummy class for shared resource strings
    public class _Shared
    {
    }
}
```

#### 2. Inject an `IHtmlLocalizer` in `_ViewImports.cshtml`

(or just put it at the top of `_Layout.cshtml`)

```cs
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<Models._Shared> SharedLocalizer
```

#### 3. Use `SharedLocalizer` in `_Layout.cshtml` instead of `Localizer`

SharedLocalizer can be used in other views as well, where you need to use the same shared resource instead of duplicating the translation in different resource files.

```html
<a class="navbar-brand" asp-page="/Index">@SharedLocalizer["Part Database"]</a>
```

**Update:** Verified that this works in a Razor Pages project.

Comment: What should I name the resx file so it knows which one to look in?

Comment: Updated my answer. It should go in a path that reflects where the dummy class is.

Comment: Still cannot seem to get it to work using this method.

Comment: If you put `@System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString()` somewhere on your page and switch culture using the query string, can you verify that the current culture actually change accordingly?

Comment: @jcmoller, yes. It came up `es`. I put it in the _Layout.cshtml page. I converted it to use [OrchardCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/portable-object-localization) and it works that with that package. I think I prefer the PO files anyway, so I might stick with them. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: @DrewChapin just verified the above solution by creating a brand new Razor Pages project from template using VS2017 15.5.2. I followed all steps above, only difference is that I am using "sv" language instead of "es".

Comment: I cloned your repo and it does indeed work. I even successfully added `es` to yours. Still cannot get it to work in my original project though.